# Identifying a movie where a man falls and gets humorously run over

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to identify an American movie that I watched on cable TV (in America) in the late 1990's or early 2000's.  But I only remember one scene from it, which I think occurred at or near the end.

The scene goes like this: A man, who I presume was the villain in the movie, falls or gets pushed from a great height.  His initial position was something man-made and outside, either a balcony or the top of a sports stadium.  In any case, he falls onto the street below, and there is some doubt about whether he's still alive.  But then a humorous scene follows where he's repeatedly run over, to make clear that he really dies.  He's flattened by a construction vehicle, he's stepped on by a marching band, etc.  The protagonist or protagonists of the movie see all this from the height the man fell from.

Can anyone help me identify this movie?  I vaguely remember it being a popular movie, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is The Naked Gun.

Here is the scene you just described:

Comment: There is a great reference to this scene in The Simpsons - [Sideshow Bob vs The Terror Lake Parade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-Okf3XY3Lw)